# Google Calendar Credentials

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, travis-ci

How do I provide the `credentials.json` file to Travis CI's build process and later on production as this is not in version control? I know of using environment variables but I am looking for a solution that uses a secret file.

Comment: https://secrethub.io/docs/guides/travis-ci/

Comment: @DaImTo, looks promising. With this, I can also provide the file in production? Like when Travis completes deployment to Heroku?